# Pressing tab to go to next TextField adds /t on that TextField

Tags: flutter

So basically when I press tab on my laptop using android emulator for Flutter /t is added on the TextField. It is not visible on the app but you can see it while debugging. It's giving me a hard time on authentication. I know that I can use split() and remove the /t but that is too much trouble adding it on all TextFields (I was thinking of making a custom widget).

I was wondering if there is any other issue similar to this that would break my authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like just using .trim() fixed the problem. From the trim() documentation it also does stuff like

```
'\tDart is fun\n'.trim(); // 'Dart is fun'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this also works on flutter web or not, but on my app it works

Define focus nodes

```
final emailFocus = FocusNode();
final passwordFocus = FocusNode();
...
```

in your `TextFormField` add

```
focusNode: emailFocus,
onFieldSubmitted: (v) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus),
...
```